# how to increase internet speed? big problem

Tags: 11.10, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are common causes for greatly decreased internet speeds?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43482/what-are-common-causes-for-greatly-decreased-internet-speeds)

i need help because when I'm downloading with ubuntu 11.10 by firefox or uget max speed is 8kb while by ubuntu software center is 70kb! what should i do? is there any code to fix it?